# VBA (32-bit) Call x86 (32-bit) DLL (C++) Keep Failing with "Type Mismatch"

Tags: vba, dll

I have been keep getting error for "type mismatch" between VBA <-> DLL

the DLL code was coded with VS C++

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

_declspec(dllexport) double _stdcall ArraySum(double *arr) {
    
    std::cout << " Called me" << arr[0] << std::endl;

    return 1.1;}
```

and VBA code to call

```
Private Declare Function testDLL _
Lib "...\Release\VBATest.dll"  Alias "ArraySum"(ByRef Arr As Double) As Double

Sub Main
    MyTest
End Sub

Sub MyTest

Dim MyX() As Double

Dim mySize As Integer

mySize = 10
ReDim MyX(mySize)

For i = 0 To mySize
MyX(i) =(i+1)
Debug.Print "Index = " & i & " arr = " & MyX(i)
Next

Dim MyResult As Double
MyResult = testDLL(MyX(0))

End Sub
```

the dll can be found, used kernel32 tested it

The debug for this process is hard because the VBA is provided by third-party, not Excel

can anyone take a look to see if I am making any stupid mistake?

BR

Comment: I think your `Declaration` is wrong. If your DLL actually expects an **array** to be passed, the VB declaration should look like `Lib "...\Release\VBATest.dll"  Alias "ArraySum"(ByRef arr() As Double) As Double`. The calling code then looks like `MyResult = testDLL(MyX())`.

Comment: @HelO'Ween shall `MyResult = testDLL(MyX())` be `MyResult = testDLL(MyX(0))` I am so confused how the array been sent to DLL to VBA
And I have also tried to make all c++ double to int, removed array, and made VBA to Long, and I have got the Wrong number of Parameters :(

Comment: No, in VBA/VB6 you pass an array with empty brackets. In the DLL (not C, though), my method signature is `Function testDLL Alias "testDLL " (psa As Dword) Export As Double`. You then retrieve the array bounds with the API calls `SafeArrayGetLBound`/`SafeArrayGetUBound` and work from there.

Comment: @HelO'Ween thanks for the suggestion,  but it does not solve my problem

Comment: Let me sum up my suggestions:
1) When passing the whole array the Declare should look like `Declare Function testDLL Lib "VBATest.dll"  Alias "ArraySum"(ByRef Arr() As Double) As Double`. Note the empty brackets.
2) When calling the DLL, the array also needs to be passed with empty brackets: `MyResult = testDLL(MyX())`
3) And as a question, because I don't speak C, is `(double *arr)` the notation for passing a pointer to a SafeArray of (VB) Double?

Comment: I've thrown together a [demo project](https://github.com/knuth-konrad/baNumbers). The DLL is written in PowerBASIC, which is a BASIC dialect that has quite some similarities with C++. Perhaps you can figure something out from it.

Comment: @HelO'Ween I have figured out where the issue coming from, it is caused decorated function name (which is also known as mangled name), in another word, the c++ made dll function name is not what the system will recognized, the ArraySum is actually "ArraySum@8"  that been exported and been recognized by VBA